# create names of loop when iterating data frame

Tags: r

```
mylist <- list(demographic_vars, usage_engagement_vars, billing_contracttype_vars, contract_type_vars)
```

Each variable in mylist is a dataframe.

I'm writing a function to pass to lapply(). I would like to loop over mylist and name a variable like so:

```
varData <- function(x) {
    paste('cv_prediction',x,sep='') <- data.frame()
}
```

Goal of the above would be this:
(e.g. for the first iteration)

```
cv_predictiondemographic_vars <- data.frame()
```

I'm getting an error in my function that I suspect is related to the above.

> Error in paste("cv_prediction", x, sep = "") <- data.frame() :
>   target of assignment expands to non-language object

If I want to create variables within my function that are the concatenation of the current value of x in a loop to some other string, how would I do that?

Comment: I guess you need `assign` if you are creating a data.frame object

Comment: Thanks but more generally how does one use the iteration name in R? E.g. in Javascript more often than not the iterator i is a number so somevar + i = something does the trick. Would I have to use paste() to mirror this in R? What is the "conventional" R way of naming vars within a loop?

Comment: Can you show a reproducible example and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s tricky. In general, you’d write the function like this:

```
varData = function(x) {
    name = paste0('cv_prediction', deparse(substitute(x), backtick = TRUE))
    assign(name, x, parent.frame())
}
```

This works when called like this, say:

```
varData(some_data_frame)
```

However, it won’t work with a loop variable since then it will use the name of *that* variable. As far as I know there’s no way of actually achieving what you want. Instead, you need to replace `list` in your above code by something else:

```
named_list = function (...) {
    names = sapply(match.call()[-1], deparse, backtick = TRUE)
    setNames(list(...), names)
}
```

And then use it:

```
mylist = named_list(demographic_vars, usage_engagement_vars, billing_contracttype_vars, contract_type_vars)
```

This will result in a `mylist` whose values are named by the objects. For example:

```
a = 1
b = 2
named_list(a, b)
# $a
# [1] 1
#
# $b
# [1] 2
```

Now you can start using the names of the list in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using eval (see [doc](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/eval.html)).

```
> varData <- function(x) {
+    eval(parse(text=paste('cv_prediction', x,' <<- data.frame()',sep='')))
+ }
> varData(3)
> ls()
[1] "cv_prediction3" "varData"
> class(cv_prediction3)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Note that instead of using `<<-` operator you can direcly address the environment where you want your new object to be created :

```
eval(parse(text=paste('cv_prediction', x,' <- data.frame()',sep='')),env=.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: While this works, `eval` is really not the right solution here — `assign` is (lower conceptual complexity, vastly more efficient, etc.).